# страничка созданная yarn build при открытии в браузере выдает ошибку

Tags: reactjs, build

есть приложение на реакте с хуками, по команду **yarn start** - все отлично строится и работает, когда делаю продакшн **yarn build** то файлы генерятся, но браузер выдает ошибку:

```
4.6b978527.chunk.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
2react-dom.production.min.js:196 ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 4 failed.
(error: http://localhost:63342/static/js/4.6b978527.chunk.js)
    at Function.p.e (http://localhost:63342/Doser_react/build/index.html?_ijt=m5pf6n1bru76o4e2pgto6lrhq7:66:21)
    at http://localhost:63342/Doser_react/build/static/js/main.60340812.chunk.js:1:4749
    at http://localhost:63342/Doser_react/build/static/js/3.c32278a2.chunk.js:2:135533
    at Nl (http://localhost:63342/Doser_react/build/static/js/3.c32278a2.chunk.js:2:135682)
    at Ru (http://localhost:63342/Doser_react/build/static/js/3.c32278a2.chunk.js:2:120463)
    at Ou (http://localhost:63342/Doser_react/build/static/js/3.c32278a2.chunk.js:2:120388)
    at ku (http://localhost:63342/Doser_react/build/static/js/3.c32278a2.chunk.js:2:117708)
    at http://localhost:63342/Doser_react/build/static/js/3.c32278a2.chunk.js:2:75786
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (http://localhost:63342/Doser_react/build/static/js/3.c32278a2.chunk.js:2:150907)
    at Yo (http://localhost:63342/Doser_react/build/static/js/3.c32278a2.chunk.js:2:75495)
vl @ react-dom.production.min.js:196
scheduler.production.min.js:14 Uncaught ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 4 failed.
(error: http://localhost:63342/static/js/4.6b978527.chunk.js)
    at Function.p.e (http://localhost:63342/Doser_react/build/index.html?_ijt=m5pf6n1bru76o4e2pgto6lrhq7:66:21)
    at http://localhost:63342/Doser_react/build/static/js/main.60340812.chunk.js:1:4749
    at http://localhost:63342/Doser_react/build/static/js/3.c32278a2.chunk.js:2:135533
    at Nl (http://localhost:63342/Doser_react/build/static/js/3.c32278a2.chunk.js:2:135682)
    at Ru (http://localhost:63342/Doser_react/build/static/js/3.c32278a2.chunk.js:2:120463)
    at Ou (http://localhost:63342/Doser_react/build/static/js/3.c32278a2.chunk.js:2:120388)
    at ku (http://localhost:63342/Doser_react/build/static/js/3.c32278a2.chunk.js:2:117708)
    at http://localhost:63342/Doser_react/build/static/js/3.c32278a2.chunk.js:2:75786
    at t.unstable_runWithPriority (http://localhost:63342/Doser_react/build/static/js/3.c32278a2.chunk.js:2:150907)
    at Yo (http://localhost:63342/Doser_react/build/static/js/3.c32278a2.chunk.js:2:75495)
p.e @ VM21231 index.html:66
(anonymous) @ DosPage.jsx:4
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:23
Nl @ react-dom.production.min.js:260
Ru @ react-dom.production.min.js:230
Ou @ react-dom.production.min.js:229
ku @ react-dom.production.min.js:223
(anonymous) @ react-dom.production.min.js:121
t.unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.production.min.js:18
Yo @ react-dom.production.min.js:120
Zo @ react-dom.production.min.js:121
Jo @ react-dom.production.min.js:120
vu @ react-dom.production.min.js:214
enqueueSetState @ react-dom.production.min.js:133
w.setState @ react.production.min.js:13
(anonymous) @ index.js:104
dosers:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

файл package.json

```
{
  "name": "no-redux",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "./",
  "dependencies": {
    "@reach/router": "^1.2.1",
    "Babel": "0.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "react": "^16.8.0-alpha.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.0-alpha.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.3.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "yarn": "^1.21.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
  }
}
```

подскажите куда копать?

Comment: Сервер который отдаёт ваши сгенерированные файлы браузеру не находит файл 4.6b978527.chunk.js:1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

проблема была в параметре - **"homepage": "./"**,
когда поменял на **"homepage": "https://domenName.com/root/"** - все заработало